# Getting an error after renewing the SSL certificate. apache webserver

Tags: apache, openssl, centos, ssl-certificate

I have replaced the certificate and private key to renew my SSL certificate on my Linux server. This is for APACHE by the way. I am positive I am using the right private key, and in the ssl.config file, I have directed the path to the correct places. 
i.e - SSLCertificateFile & SSLCertificateKeyFile.

But I still get this error below:

" AH01909: RSA certificate configured for hostname:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed May 20 21:17:33.432341 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2607] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Wed May 20 21:17:33.432366 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2607] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch"

what could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

@Oluwatobi Elugbadebo. It sounds like you have used the wrong hostname to generate the certificates.   Not knowing your environment, I cannot comment further.  However I would recommend using Let's Encrypt / Certbot for free ssl and very minimal setup to turnkey add SSL to any apache2 hosted domain.  It will handle everything related to the cert and modification of apache files.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7